# Error: '0.type' is null or not an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am getting the error below when I click the button that calls the JavaScript to do the validation.  The strange thing is that everything was working before but I am not what happened now.  If I select to ignore this error:

```
Error: '0.type' is null or not an object
```

then the code works fine but I get the error first then it asks me if i want to debug it, if i select No then the code works fine.   Please help.  thanks
it seems the code stops at this line:

```
 if (areas[0].type == "textarea") {
```

but here is my entire code:

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
    function Validate_1() {
        var flag = false;
        var gridView = document.getElementById('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>');

        for (var i = 1; i < gridView.rows.length; i++) {
            var selects = gridView.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('select');
            //var inputs = gridView.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
            var areas = gridView.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('textarea');
            if (selects != null && areas != null) {
                if (areas[0].type == "textarea") {
                    var txtval = areas[0].value;
                    var selectval = selects[0].value;
                    if (selectval == "No" && (txtval == "" || txtval == null)) {

                        flag = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        flag = true;
                        document.getElementById('<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>').style.visibility = 'visible';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (!flag) {
            alert('Please note that comments are required if you select "No" from the dropdown box.  Thanks');
            document.getElementById('<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            // areas[i].focus();
            // areas.[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
        }
        return flag;
    }
    //  document.getElementById('<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>').style.visibility = 'visible';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var areas = gridView.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('textarea');
```

`getElementsByTagNane` does not return null, the length would be zero

So your if check needs to change.

```
if (selects != null && areas != null)
```

should be

```
if (selects.length && areas.length)
```